Cannot orchestrate typescript + node + ESNext modules
UPDATE now includes an answer!
So I want to publish a typescript module, but I have an either-or problem importing the modules I need or exporting the module correctly.
Here is a minimum repro case, with some variants I have tried.

Here is the test case, a simple javascript file:

import { fileType } from "@m87/hello";

console.log(fileType("../file1.jpg"));


Here is the example module (from a hello directory, as in hello world):

import { Mime } from 'mime'

export const fileType = async (file: string): string => {
  const mime = new Mime();
  return mime.getType(file) || "";
}



Here are some configuration options and their errors:

package.json : type = module
{
  "name": "@m87/hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mime": "4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.5.4",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  }
}

tsconfig.json :: commented-out defaults redacted
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2023",
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    "strict": true,                  
    "skipLibCheck": true      
  }
}

In this configuration, the code builds, but attempting to run it generates this error:
import { fileType } from "@m87/hello";
         ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module '@m87/hello' does not provide an export named 'fileType'

For completeness, the test is run with "type":"module" in it's package.json also, and this is the output index.js post "compile":
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.fileType = void 0;
const mime_1 = require("mime");
const fileType = async (file) => {
    const mime = new mime_1.Mime();
    return mime.getType(file) || "";
};
exports.fileType = fileType;

I don't know quite why fileType is defined twice in this output, but in any case, the last one does look correct?
Ok some variants.
(1) Turn off "type":"module"
If I turn off "type":"module" in package.json of the hello module:
const mime_1 = require("mime");
               ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /code/hello/node_modules/mime/dist/src/index.js from /code/hello/dist/index.js not supported.

Although the module builds, when run it cannot import the mime module.
(2) set tsconfig to "module":"ES6" instead of commonjs
Now build fails with:
lib/index.ts:1:22 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'mime'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

1 import { Mime } from 'mime'

(3) ok, what about moduleResolution = nodenext?
This ends up requiring "module": "NodeNext" in tsconfig also...
AND this turns out to be the answer.
So, hours of googling, chatgpting, document reading later... I finally have an answer.
May it help someone else.

Given SyntaxError: The requested module '@m87/mdc-ts' does not provide an export named 'caption', have you tried importing it without destructuring, and looking at what's in it? E.g. import mdcts from "@m87/mdc-ts"; console.log(mdcts); (that said: that package is not on npm so you may need to explain where you're even getting this library from)

When I try that, I get an error that there is no default export, so I was unable to get that either.

Then you'll definitely want to make sure this is a [mcve], because right now no one will be able to confirm this. Also note that you don't need node-fetch, Node has the standard Fetch API built into every currently supported version of Node.

node-fetch has functionality that node's fetch does not, which I was using. But I did re-implement everything without relying on any external node libraries. Re implementing a mime map seemed particularly stupid. I'll try for a full but minimal repro example later today. It's confounding.

Why would you need to reimplement a mime map? node-fetch doesn't come with one, nor does it automagically send the right Content-Type header? The express intent of node-fetch is to be identical to the window.fetch function you're familiar with from the browser.

I'll post the minimum, but my other dependency, file-type or mime encountered the same problem. I do need to send the file type. I now have a minimum repro case, and will update.
